# ¿Como puedo disminuir el tamaño de los indices sin utilizar rebuild o reorganize?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, windows, index

Estoy preparando un mantenimiento para una bd que esta en uso todo el tiempo. El tema principal es que los indices pesan casi el triple que la data, por lo tanto no es viable reconstruir o reorganizarlos para evitar noquear la operación. Intente comprimiéndolos pero en seguida se alarma el uso de cpu

Comment: Si llevas tu auto a mantenimiento, tienes que dejar de usarlo; bajo la promesa de devolvértelo lo antes posible. Por eso los mantenimientos se programan en la ventana de tiempo de menor uso. No hay mucho que hacerle a los índices, salvo eliminarlos, incluso temporalmente; aunque sí se puede revisar la cardinalidad de ellos y valorar su utilidad, ya que no es raro encontrarse el abuso de ellos. Con [`DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-show-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) puedes obtener información útil para evaluar.

Comment: Se necesita más información. Nada será gratuito. Se pueden reconstruir los índices en línea con la edición Enterprise, pero seguirá siendo una operación costosa. Es probable que haya índices innecesarios o mal diseñados y por eso pesan tanto.

Comment: Tal parece, Irene, que habrá que analizar cuáles índices están siendo utilizado, cuáles vale la pena mantener y cuáles definitivamente se deben eliminar. Database tuning es más que click derecho reparar. Hay much análisis detrás, y lo debe hacer el DBA. Si tú eres la DBA, enhorabuena, tienes la oportunidad de brillar frente a tu equipo.